# Yarn does not update local dependency

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I have a local dependency in `package.json` of the form “pkg”: “file:../pkg”.

How can I convince `yarn 1.3.2` to fetch the new content of the pkg to `node_modules`?

Comment: Yarn supports local dependencies via `yarn add file:/path/to/local/folder` so updating a dep should be `yarn upgrade file:/path/to/local/folder`. I can't test myself though sorry

Comment: I tried yarn upgrade pkg, which didn’t work. Is yarn upgrade file:../pkg different?

Comment: yeah can you try `yarn upgrade file:../pkg` and let me know how that goes? Pretty sure that should work

Comment: I'm working on a node_module and using `yarn upgrade` worked. Is there a way to link the node_module directly to my local package? I would like to avoid running yarn upgrade every time I make a change in the module that I'm developing.

Comment: @ErickM.Sprengel If you're working on a yarn module, use `yarn link` instead, it's meant for this kind of situation

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can upgrade the dependencies with `yarn upgrade`. If it takes too much time, you can upgrade just certain packages `yarn upgrade pkg` in your case